# Asymptotic analysis comparision for $2^n$ and $(3/2)^n$

Tags: asymptotics

> 1) $$f(n) = 2^n\,,\quad g(n) = (3/2) ^ n$$

Is $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$? Can someone please explain this to me ?

> 2)$$f(n) = n^2+\log n\,,\quad   g(n) = n^2$$

I know that $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$  but how can I get the constant $c$ to prove the equation for $\Theta$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of "big O" notation?

Comment: $0 \leq f(n) \leq c g(n)$ is that a  trick question. I thought the first one is big O but I looked at solution online which says it is $\theta$. I  need a confirmation hence I posted it here.

Comment: How did you prove that $ f=\Theta (g) $?

Comment: we can do that by limits $\lim_{n \to +\infty}  f(n)/g(n)$ will be a constant which is not zero.

Comment: I am reading algorithm design manual by steve skeina in book it mentions if f or g doesn't dominate then we get a constant which is not 0.  $0 \leq c1 g(n) \leq f(n) \leq c2 g(n)$

Comment: Yes, this is the definition.

Comment: But in the first problem the limit of $f/g$ is infinite!

Comment: Yes that is why it confused me. I wanted to make sure it is big oh.

Comment: The first one is not true. The second one yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second problem, just note that, $\forall n \geq 1$

$$ |f(n)| = |n^2+\log n| < n^2 + n \leq 2 n^2,$$

where the fact that $\log(n) < n $ has been used. For the other inequality, observe that

$$ |f(n)| = |n^2+\log n| \geq n^2,  $$

since $\ln(n)\geq 0$ $\forall n\geq 1$.