# How to find $n^2 - 2n - 3$ is $\Omega(n^2)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

How can I show that $n^2 - 2n - 3$ is $\Omega(n^2)$?

Comment: What is $\Omega(n^2)$?

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Did you down-vote my question? If $f(x)$ is $\Omega(n^2)$ it means that $f(x) \ge \Omega(n^2)$ for some values $C$ and $k$ such that $x \ge k$ and $C$ is a constant multiple of $n^2$.

Comment: I did not downvote; I was just curious about the definition of that symbol. I thought of it as big $O$. Clearly this is not the case, though. Also, what does $f(x)\ge \Omega(n^2)$ mean? You define $\Omega(n^2)$ by means of itself?

Comment: Oh, no problemo.  Yeah, I barely understand Big-O.  Big-Omega is apparently the opposite.  $\ge$ intsead of $\le$.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431372/asymptotic-analysis-comparision-for-2n-and-3-2n).

Answer (score 2):

Since $2n+3$ is positive for any choice of $n$, $$n^2-2n-3\leq n^2$$
for any $n\geq 1$.

Now, $$-\frac 1 3 n^2\leq -3$$ and $$-\frac 1 3 n^2\leq -2n$$ when $n\geq 5$. Thus $$n^2-\frac 23n^2=\frac 13n^2\leq n^2-2n-3$$ when $n\geq 5$. We can then write $$\frac 13n^2\leq n^2-2n-3\leq n^2$$ for $n\geq 5$

Comment: How did you come up with the $-1/3$ coefficient?

Comment: Trial and error.

Comment: You have to argue that is also true when $n\geq 2$.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. When $n \ge 2$, $-1 n^2 \le -3$.

Comment: So I took a break and came back to this problem.  I came up with $C = -1$ and $k \ge 2$.  Would those be appropriate witnesses to say that $n^2 - 2n - 3$ is $\Omega (n^2)$?

Comment: Update: My logic is:  $n^2 \le n^2$ when $n>=1$ and $C=1$, $n^2 \le -2n$ when $n>=2$, and $C=-1$ and $n^2 \le -3$ when $n>=2$ and $C =-1$.  Summing the coefficients results in $-1$ and the $max(k_1,k_2,k_3) = 2$.